# cant do factory reset or hard reset on mi 5x

Tags: factory-reset, xiaomi, hard-reset

I tried to factory reset my mi 5x phone through settings but after clicking reset device, it just turn off the phone and restart it without changing anything on the phone.

And when I try to do a hard reset, after holding <kbd>Vol down</kbd> + <kbd>power</kbd> button, this screen shows up:

[image: fastboot screen]

And after a few seconds the phone turn off again.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Well, first a [hard reset](/tags/hard-reset/info) would not imply any key presses, but taking the battery out :) As the key combo you've used led you into [fastboot](/tags/fastboot/info) mode, try the other volume key instead (i.e. volUp+Power). Does that bring you to the recovery menu and lets you factory-reset?

Comment: @Izzy No It just turn on the phone when i use Vol up + power button.

Comment: @MiladHeydari have you messed up with recovery partition ?

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui no. what i described is all i could do. it never gave me the chance to mess up anything :D

Comment: Broken volume up button or something?

Comment: @Izzy What if the device has an internal battery ? ;)

Comment: @esQmo_ in that case you press and hold the power button until it reboots (that's also supposed to cut power after 10..30s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the comments above, I can think  your volume up button may be broken? But remember, you can perform  a factory reset from the Fastboot mode too, simply connect your phone to the computer, install **Minimal ADB & Fastboot** (Windows), run it then type `fastboot -w`[press enter] the phone should be reset.

Also ADB lets you do many things on your phone including factory reset:

- Enable ADB (USB Debugging) from the Developer's menu
- Connect the phone to the computer
- Run Minimal ADB & Fastboot
- Type `adb shell` [press enter]
- Type `wipe data` [press enter]

You're done.

ADB can let you boot in recovery mode and perform factory reset manually:

- Type `adb reboot recovery` [press enter]

PS: *Don't forget to install drivers to let your phone be detected by the computer.*

Not on Windows ? Check [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/186278) related to a minimal installation of ADB for all operating systems.

Check also our [ADB tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info)

Comment: +1 :) And even if not Windows, our [adb tag-wiki](/tags/adb/info) mentions a post named [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](/q/42474/16575) (<- shameless self-promotion :)